# What's the meaning of the indirect cmd used in glMultiDrawElementsIndirect

Tags: opengl, jogl

I'm confused about using glMultiDrawElementsIndirect(), could anyone explain to me the meaning of the cmd struct used by that drawing command?

struct cmd:

```
count = ..
primCount = ..
firstIndex = ..
baseVertex = ..
baseInstance = ..
```

if I have three different triangle strips to draw, would that be like this?

```
for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
{
    count = indexCount;
    primCount = 1;
    firstIndex = n * count;
    baseVertex = 0;
    baseInstance = n;
    ...
}
```

Setup Buffers:

```
protected void setupBuffers()
{
    gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, vaoBuff);
    gl.glBindVertexArray(vaoBuff.get(0));

    gl.glGenBuffers(5, vboBuff);

    //bind indirect buffer object
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, vboBuff.get(0));
    gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, instanceCount * 5 * Integer.SIZE / 8, null, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBufferSubData(...);

    //bind draw instance ID in the shader with a buffer object
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboBuff.get(1));
    gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceCount * Integer.SIZE / 8, drawIndexBuff, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glVertexAttribIPointer(d_idLoc, 1, GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, 0);
    gl.glVertexAttribDivisor(d_idLoc, 1);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(d_idLoc);

    //bind vertex data buffer object
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboBuff.get(2));
    gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceCount / column_subdivision * vertBuffSize * Float.SIZE / 8, null, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBufferSubData(...);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(verPosLoc, 3, GL4.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(verPosLoc);

    //bind vertex index data buffer object
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboBuff.get(3));
    gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceCount / column_subdivision * indexBuffSize * Integer.SIZE / 8, null, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBufferSubData(...);

    //bind texture coordinate data buffer object
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboBuff.get(4));
    gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceCount / column_subdivision * texBuffSize * Float.SIZE / 8, null, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBufferSubData(...);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(tc_inLoc, 2, GL4.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(tc_inLoc);
}
```

drawing command:

```
gl.glBindVertexArray(vaoBuff.get(0));
glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, vboBuff.get(0));
gl.glMultiDrawElementsIndirect(GL4.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, null, 3, 0);
```

Fixed it, there're some problems within the vertex data. The other is all correct.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more context leading up to your `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect (...)` command? One thing I am not sure you accounting for is that the `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER` binding is not stored in a Vertex Array Object -  `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` on the other hand is. So in addition to binding a VAO, before you make the call to `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect (...)` you would need to make sure the binding to `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER` was setup correctly.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman  I just added that to the post. In fact even if I didn't do that it's also correct. Since I have did that during setting up buffers. And that shouldn't be the wrong place. Since object appears on the screen, just it didn't appear right.

Comment: Hi Oscar, have you solved it?

Comment: Yeap. Thanks @elect. It's been a while. Just check the newest blue book or red book, where you can find detailed answers. Not a good question to be put here.

Comment: May you just tell me if you ever got `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect` working with a buffer instead passing `null`?